# Scala Option type not inferred as expected

Tags: scala, scala-option

I'm writing a function to get an entry from a `JSONObject`. Since it is JSON the entry by the input name may or may not exist and so the function return an `Option` which will be `None` when the `Try` fails or if the value is `NULL` on success. The function fails to compile and errors about incorrect return type.

```
def tryGet[T](jsonObject: JSONObject, name: String): Option[T] = {
  Try(jsonObject.get(name))
    .map(x => if(JSONObject.NULL.equals(x)) None else x.asInstanceOf[T])
    .toOption
}
```

Error:

`Expression of type Option[Any] doesn't conform to expected type Option[T]`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Also, is this the idiomatic way to approach the problem?

Update:

Changing to the below works

```
def tryGet[T](jsonObject: JSONObject, name: String): Option[T] = {
    Try(jsonObject.get(name))
      .filter(!JSONObject.NULL.equals(_))
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
      .toOption
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
.map( x => if(x.equals(null)) None else x.asInstanceOf[T])
This has type `Option[Nothing]` ^         ^ This has type `T`
```

You have both an `Option[Nothing]` and a `T` in the if/else statement. The result type of if/else is the least upper-bound (the nearest common type) of the result type of `if` and the result type of `else`. In this case, they have nothing in common but `Any`. So the the result is `Try[Any]` which gets converted to `Option[Any]` by `toOption`.

If you really need to check for `null`, use `filter` instead.

```
def tryGet[T](jsonObject: JSONObject, name: String): Option[T] =
    Try(jsonObject.get(name))
        .map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
        .filter(_ != null)
        .toOption
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the null check, and  "None" and "T" are two possible result in the map, so the type  will be mapped to Any instead of "T" in your code. Check this:

```
Try(jsonObject.get(name)).map( _.asInstanceOf[T]).toOption
```

Then you might need something like this:

```
val NullJson:Option[T] = None
Try(jsonObject.get(name)).map( x=>if(x.equals(null)) NullJson else Option(x.asInstanceOf[T])).toOption.flatten
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it throws "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.String" at runtime as it is trying to cast a null to String.

Comment: @broun You should write which json library you are using. I think your json library is not returning `null`, instead it is returning non-null object `org.json.JSONObject$Null`

Comment: yeah, just figured that it is returning a custom NULL type. I was checking java null instead

Comment: Adding filter to the try does the trick. Thanks for the help.